# ActiveRecord validation in join model strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two entities associated via a `has_many through` linked by a join model that performs some validations. However, when the validation fails, even though the link is not persisted, the object exists. I must be doing something incorrect...

```
class Aklass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :bklasses, through: :links
end

class Bklass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  has_many :aklasses, through: :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :aklass
  belongs_to :bklass

  validate :fail_validation

  def fail_validation
    errors.add(:base, 'Always fails')
  end
end
```

Rails console session:

```
rails c
a = Aklass.new
b = Bklass.new
a.links
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
a.bklasses << b
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Always fails
a.links
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Link id: nil, aklass_id: 1, bklass_id: 1>]>
```

I understand it not persisting, because the validation failed, but the "hanging around" of the association object gets the application on an inconsistent state, because it allows for querying things like `a.links.first.bklass`, which doesnt make sense to me since the validation failed...

What am I doing incorrectly? What would be the best practice for validations of has_many through associations?

Comment: If validation fails, the record is not saved, but it does not change any  data in the object in memory. Would you prefer that foreign keys were nullified? And what should happen to other fields (not references) in the object if validation fails?

Comment: Apparently the object has to exist so the errors have some place to live. And I am ok with that. I had to add a `a.links.last.persisted?` in my code, but it smells so bad....  With regards to other fields, they were null because the validation failed before setting them (they are set in an after_create)